# AngularJS ngIf does not animate on content change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular [ngIf documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf) says

> ### Animations
>
> enter - happens just after the ngIf **contents change** and a new DOM element is created and injected into the ngIf container

I have had problems with this and therefore made this **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JOx9hJL3aKSrUNSJJmN1?p=preview)** which shows that change to content does not trigger the enter animation. However, if I set the content to `undefined` and wrap the initialization in a 1ms `$timeout` it works as I expect.

Why is it not triggering the *enter* and *leave* when I just change the content as the documentation says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **ngIf** directive shows the animation when the expression *changes*. As it is an if expression it only knows about true and false.
When the expression changes from an true to a true, the animation is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you force you model - item - to change, by assining undefinied value and then the Date object. If you want to append a new item to the list you should use ng-repeat.

Comment: I don't want to append a new item, I want to change the item. And when I change it, the animation should happen. The reason I assign it to `undefined` is to solve the problem. It should not be necessary.